# How to monitor RAID in Solaris 10 x86 on PowerEdge 2650 with PERC 3/Di

Tags: raid, solaris, dell, dell-poweredge, solaris-10

I have a PowerEdge 2650 with the PERC 3/Di RAID controller.

The OS installed is Solaris 10 8/07 U4.

Currently RAID is configured through the BIOS and it works fine, but I have no way to monitor the status of the drives.

Is there a command to show me the status of the drives?  Drivers I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you would use the OpenManage Server Administrator to monitor Dell hardware.  This is available for download from Dell's support website for Windows and Linux.  I do not know if they make a version compatible with Solaris specifically.

Comment: Wondering - Can you get the DRAC to monitor and connect to IT Assistant without agents on the OS?

Comment: Good question, but I have not used DRAC cards, so I am not sure.  Perhaps someone with more experience with those cards can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

In a supported OS you can use Server Administrator but I don't think there is a version for Solaris, at least now there isn't, you probably could find more info in linux.dell.com, also you have the option of the original manufacturer of the Raid controller, Adaptec, but now I can't remember the Adaptec model, probably a google search will help.

Answer (score 0):

The 2650 is getting old - even on a supported OS, you may encounter difficulties trying to install OMSA. Here is a guide to get OMSA on to a 2650 running CentOS 5 - http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2010/10/how-to-install-dell-omsa-5-5-on-a-dell-poweredge-2650-with-centos-5-rhel-5/

I believe Solaris has some level of linux compatibility, but I cannot verify whether this will work.